# How to make sure all connected clients received data sent through Websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm experimenting broadcasting media (webcam, recorded videos -- like TV) over the internet through websocket (currently only works on Chrome). It is working fine in controlled environment.

However, when put it on test in real life environment most of the times the clients did not receive data sent from the other end.

Here's how I set my websocket configuration (**for example only**):

```
var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://74.13.452.171:8080');

websocket.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    // do something with e.data
});
```

So how to make sure that all clients visiting a certain page of the web site received data sent from another client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you want to see real problem the site is meldville dot com

Comment: it depends entirely on the server code, which is not shown...

Comment: also, http is a lot better for broadcasting media than sockets, at least at this point...

Comment: hi dandavis, can you suggest what server code to solve this problem, I use einaros's ws websocket library -- thanks

Comment: i add to an array of ws.send() methods onconnect and remove the function ondisconnect. i subscribe the message event to a function that iterates the array and calls each send() function with e.data to broadcast to all connected clients.

Comment: do yo have example - thanks

Comment: have a look at WebRTC, it's designed specifically for streaming media. Less work for you.

Comment: Thanks Touffy, that is not the future, my aim is something like Meerkat or Periscope